# Нужна ли запятая после «что»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, спп, деепричастный-оборот

*Они осознают, что(,) научившись властвовать над собой, им удалось подчинить себе остальных.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Заданное предложение: *Они осознают, что, **научившись властвовать** над собой, им **удалось подчинить** себе остальных.*

1. В чем **неправильность** этого предложения? А точно ли оно неправильное? Ошибка не очень заметна, можно и пропустить. Наше сознание скользит по тексту, считывая смысл. А смысл как раз ясен. Но если остановить внимание, то понимаешь: да, с этим предложением **что-то не так.**
2. И первая версия: **деепричастный** оборот и **безличное** предложение. А что же еще! Но с деепричастным оборотом здесь все в порядке. Вот у Розенталя:

   ```
   В ряде случаев возможно употребление деепричастного 
   оборота, не выражающего действия подлежащего: 2) в 
   безличном предложении при ИНФИНИТИВЕ, например: 
   Приходилось РАБОТАТЬ в трудных условиях, НЕ ИМЕЯ 
   в течение многих недель ни одного свободного дня для 
   отдыха.
   ```

В заданном предложении  действие, выраженное **деепричастным** оборотом, совершает тот же субъект, что и в **безличном** предложении, хотя там подлежащее отсутствует (они, им удалось).

3. Так как же **найти ошибку?** Попробуем по содержанию заданного текста построить **правильное** предложение. Получается такой вариант: *Не научившись властвовать даже над собой, они все-таки **смогли**  подчинить себе остальных.*

Здесь **уступительное** значение у деепричастного оборота (хотя не научились, а смогли), а в заданном предложении значение **причины:** И там должно быть так: *Научившись властвовать  над собой, они  **смогли**  подчинить себе остальных.*

4. Итак, противоречие **в семантике глаголов**: *научившись властвовать — им удалось.* Не им удалось, а они смогли/сумели. Нужно обозначить не полученную возможность, а активное действие. А ***удаться*** — это когда просто **повезло.**

**Редактирование** предложения:

*Они осознают, что, **научившись властвовать** над собой, он **смогли подчинить** себе остальных.*

Редактирование связано **не с  безличным предложением**, а с заменой глагола (не им удалось а они смогли).

**УДАТЬСЯ** св. 2. безл. кому, с инф. Представиться, оказаться возможным. Не удалось встретиться кому-л. Задуманное удалось осуществить. Удалось достать билет на поезд.

Answer (score 3):

Запятая после ***что*** ставится по этому [правилу](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113) (Розенталь):

> **2.** Деепричастный оборот, стоящий после союза сочинительного или подчинительного либо союзного слова, отделяется от него запятой (такой оборот можно «оторвать» от союза и переставить в другое место предложения):
> *Наш отец Чимша-Гималайский был из кантонистов, но, **выслужив офицерский чин,** оставил нам потомственное дворянство и именьишко* (Ч.); *Жизнь устроена так дьявольски, что, **не умея ненавидеть,** невозможно искренне любить* (Ж. Г.); *Становилось слышно, как, **отсчитывая секунды с точностью метронома,** капает из крана вода* (Пауст.).

Но предложение составлено некорректно.
[**Неправильное употребление причастного и деепричастного оборота**](https://obrazovaka.ru/russkiy-yazyk/oshibki-v-upotreblenii-deeprichastnyh-oborotov):

> Деепричастный оборот в безличном предложении.
> **Примеры ошибок:** Наблюдая за облаками, мне было спокойно. Выйдя на улицу, ему стало жарко.

Comment: Предложение действительно составлено некорректно, но причина здесь другая.  А какая?

Comment: @Sharon  Может, в глаголах?.. Властвовать -- подчинить. Но и в безличности тоже.

Comment: По безличности нормально,  Розенталь пункт 1 (2) http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/69.htm

Comment: @Sharon  Про инфинитив я помню. Меня смутило "удалось". // Пусть авторы ломают голову над предложением -- на вопрос о запятой после "что" я ответил.

Comment: Это да, ответили. Но разве вам неинтересно найти ошибку?)